# Get-ADUser failing on certain properties on a single machine

Tags: powershell

The problem machine is running Windows 7, Powershell 5.0.10586.117.

This is an odd problem that seems to indicate something wrong in the environment on one machine, but I can't seem to track it down.  Essentially, the problem is that when I run

```
Get-ADUser username -Properties *
```

I get the following error:

```
Get-ADUser : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser username -Properties *
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (username:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], NullReferenceException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

I ran the same command on a 2012r2 box (PS version 4.0), and it completes without issue.

Running the command without `-Properties *` on the Win7 box, the command will complete successfully.  Additionally, I can just tack attributes on to `-Properties` as well like `-Properties AccountExpirationDate,POBox,telephoneNumber'` and the command will complete successfully as well.  Finally, I built an array of all AD attributes and isolated it down to four attributes that cause different errors on the Win7 box.

The `PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount, CompoundIdentitySupported, AuthenticationPolicySilo, AuthenticationPolicy'` properties cause an Invalid argument exception on the Win7 box.

The `PrimaryGroup` property causes a NullReferenceException.

When extracting these properties via a successful run of the command on the 2012r2 box (or essentially any machine, except for the problem Win7 one), they have the following values:

```
AuthenticationPolicy                 : {}
AuthenticationPolicySilo             : {}
CompoundIdentitySupported            : {}
PrimaryGroup                         : CN=Domain Users,OU=BuiltInUsers,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com
PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount : {}
```

I'm not using a Powershell profile on the Win7 box, and AFAIK, I have made no major modifications to the environment.  I haven't gone to far as uninstall everything back to defaults and start over, so I'm hoping that someone might have an idea regarding what is causing this.

Comment: I'd check the version of RSAT tools installed on the W7 box.  Sounds like they may be out of date.

Comment: From the best I can tell, there is only version of RSAT tools for Win7 available for download, and that is the version that is installed.  I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the module itself, but no luck there.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from trial and error, and a bunch of research on this issue myself,
there are some accounts that have 
PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount, 
CompoundIdentitySupported, 
AuthenticationPolicySilo, 
AuthenticationPolicy
ACLs will display this error.
you can use a try/catch to loop through the ad users instead:

```
    $ids= Get-ADUser -Filter *
    foreach ($id in $IDs) {
        Try {
            $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $id -Properties *
            Write-Host "Success: $($user.name)"
        }
        Catch {
            # continue to next
            Write-Host "Failure: $($user.name)"
        }
    }
```